# Introduction to Linear Algebra 4ed by Gilbert Strang, Problem Set 2.7 Problem 38

Tags: linear-algebra

It is a problem in Section 2.7 Transposes and Permuations. If you take powers of a permutation matrix, why is some $P^k$ eventually equal to $I$? Find a $5$ by $5$ permutation $P$ so that the smallest power to equal $I$ is $P^{6}$.

The solution states that

> There are $n!$ permutation matrices of order $n$. Eventually two powers of
> $P$ must be the same: If $P^r = P^s$, then $P^{r-s}=I$.

And the satisfied matrix is
$$
  \begin{bmatrix}
    P_2 & \\\
    & P_3
  \end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
  P_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 \\\
    1 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}, P_3 = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 0 \\\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\\
    1 & 0 & 0
  \end{bmatrix}.
$$

My question is

1. Why "there must be $P^r = P^s$"?
2. How to effectively find such 5 by 5 matrix $P$?

Comment: $P^0, P^1, \dots, P^{n!}$ is a list of $n! + 1$  permutation matrices, so not all of them can be different

Comment: Also, do you know about permutation groups in general?

Comment: @Keplerto Oh, I don't know the knowledge of "group".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Permutation matrices permute the elements of a vector, if your permutation matrix is a $n\times n$-matrix then it will permute the elements of vectors with $n$ elements. This means there are only $n!$ different permutation matrices. Meaning the list ${P^k}_{k=0,\ldots n!}$ contains $n!+1$ permutation matrices, meaning at least 2 have to be the same (pigeonhole principle).
2. What the people in the solution did is seeing the following:
   The first $k$ for which $P_2^k=I=P_3^k$ is when $k=6$ since the first equality holds for $k$ a multiple of 2 and the second one holds for $k$ a multiple of 3 and $\text{lcm}(2,3)=6$. Then they saw that
   $$\begin{pmatrix}P_2&\\&P_3\end{pmatrix}^k = \begin{pmatrix}P_2^k&\\&P_3^k\end{pmatrix}.$$
   This way they effectively reduced the question to two smaller similar question that were easier to solve.